# Parameterizing a wierd surface.

Tags: graphing-functions, surfaces, mathematica, parametrization

I need to parameterize the following surface so I can display it in Mathematica. 
$$
x = -\cos(yz)
$$
Help on setting the bounds so that it fits within the following bounds is also appreciated.
$$
\begin{array}{rcccl}
0 &\leq& x &\leq& 0.5 \\
-1 &\leq& y &\leq& 1 \\
-1 &\leq& z &\leq& 1
\end{array}
$$
Thanks!

Comment: Can't you just use $y$ and $z$ as parameters?

Comment: `ContourPlot3D[x == -Cos[y z], {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, {z, -1, 1}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your plot is empty:  for $-1 \le y \le 1$ and $-1 \le z \le 1$, we have $-\pi/2 < -1 \le yz \le 1 < \pi/2$, consequently $\cos yz > 0$ and $-\cos yz < 0$.  Your stated range for $x$ does not result in any such points satisfying the given equation.

Ignoring your stated range for $x$, we can use the *Mathematica* command

```
ParametricPlot3D[{-Cos[u v], u, v}, {u, -1, 1}, {v, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> All]
```

to get a plot with the natural parametrization $y = u$, $z = v$.

Comment: Thanks. I feel kinda dumb seeing the answer now but I suspect that I should get used to this being an engineering student.